# Getting the field names from a Linq To Sql object

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Linq expression which I'd like to insert to a ADO.NET datatable.
I would like to know the name of the fields from the query in order to set the datatable name.
Here is an example of my code:

```
var result=from item in context.table
           select new{
                field1=... ,
                field2=... ,
                field3=...
           };
```

What I'd like to do is to set the tables name.

```
Datatable.Columns.Add("field1"); .. etc
```

I tried to do it manually but I believe there should be an elegant solution for it.

Thanks

Comment: Use Reflection. `Type.GetProperties()`

Comment: You named field1, ... manually now you want set them dynamically?

Comment: Yes Saeed , Leppie do u have an example for that?

Comment: @DavidRasuli: I posted an answer now, due to the 'ugliness' of the other solutions. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By making use of reflection you can extract the names of the properties of your anonymous type created in the LINQ expression.

```
var result = from item in context.table
    select new {
         field1 = ... ,
         field2 = ... ,
         field3 = ... };

if (result.Any())
{
    Type t = result.First().GetType();
    foreach (PropertyInfo p in t.GetProperties())
    {
        // Get the name of the prperty
        Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried to do it , but result.GetType().GetProperties()'s count seems to be 0.

Comment: @DavidRasuli  - there is bit change in code i added ToList to query and gettting property of the first element only by using result[0].GetType(); try that out

Comment: `var pi = (from p in t.GetProperties() select p).ToList();` Serious useless LINQ abuse there.

Comment: Protip: you should be using `results.Any()` instead of `results.Count() > 0`.

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion:

```
var result=from item in context.table
           select new{
                field1=... ,
                field2=... ,
                field3=...
           };

static IEnumerable<string> GetPropertyNames<T>(IEnumberable<T> lst) 
{
  foreach (var pi in typeof(T).GetProperties())
  {
    yield return pi.Name;
  }
}

var propnames = GetPropertyNames(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

This might be bit simpler ;) ...

```
var fieldNames = (from p in query.GetType().GetProperties() select p.Name).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `select new` creates an anonymous type, there isn't a short elegant solution that I know of, but you can do what you want. The idea here is that you will take the first item returned by the query, and using the type information of the anonymous type, we can reflect its properties and fill your `DataTable`.

We can do this using the following method that takes a `DataTable` and the `Type` information of the anonymous type.

```
public static void FillColumns(DataTable table, Type anonymousType) {
    PropertyInfo[] properties = anonymousType.GetProperties();

    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties) {
        table.Columns.Add(property.Name);
    }
}
```

Then for example you can do something like this

```
var result = from item in context.Table
            select new {
                field1 = item.f1,
                field2 = item.f2,
                field3 = item.f3
            };

if (result.Count() != 0) {
    DataTable table = new DataTable("Table");
    FillColumns(table, result.First().GetType());
}
```

Your `DataTable` in this short example would yield 3 columns `field1`, `field2`, and `field3`.
**Edit** Already invested the time, so might as well post the full working example.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Reflection;

    #region Fake Database

    internal class DatabaseMock
    {
        private DatabaseMock() { 
            // Hides the default public constructor created by the compiler
            // Uses the factory pattern for creation instead
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new instance of a database with three default items
        /// </summary>
        public static DatabaseMock Create() {
            DatabaseMock database = new DatabaseMock();

            List<ItemMock> items = new List<ItemMock>();
            items.Add(new ItemMock("item1"));
            items.Add(new ItemMock("item2"));
            items.Add(new ItemMock("item3"));

            database.Table = items;

            return database;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the items in the database
        /// </summary>
        public IEnumerable<ItemMock> Table {
            get;
            private set;
        }
    }

    internal struct ItemMock
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the ItemMock class
        /// </summary>
        public ItemMock(string value) {
            _value = value;
        }

        private string _value;
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the items value
        /// </summary>
        public string Value {
            get {
                return _value;
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Takes the specified DataTable and anonymous type information, and populates the table with a new DataColumn per anonymous type property
        /// </summary>
        public static void FillColumns(DataTable table, Type anonymousType) {
            PropertyInfo[] properties = anonymousType.GetProperties();

            foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties) {
                table.Columns.Add(property.Name);
            }
        }

        static void Main() {
            DatabaseMock database = DatabaseMock.Create();

            var query =
                from item in database.Table
                select new {
                    field1 = item.Value,
                    field2 = item.Value,
                    field3 = item.Value
                };

            if (query.Count() != 0) {
                DataTable table = new DataTable("Table");
                FillColumns(table, query.First().GetType());

#if DEBUG
                foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns) {
                    Debug.WriteLine(column.ColumnName);
                }
#endif
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: David, this doesn't retrives the right names, it retrives the names of the original table (items at your case) and not field1,2,3

Comment: I ran the example multiple times and it returns field1, field2, and field3. It wouldn't output the names of the original table unless you passed in the type information for context.Table, which is not what this example does. Make sure you are passing in the type information for `result.First().GetType()` and not `context.Table`.

Comment: Could be my bad, I'll check it

Comment: This can be made much 'prettier' with proper use of generics.

Comment: I don't see any urgent necessity for the overhead of generics for special-case code here.

Comment: @DavidAnderson: Your code will fail if the list is empty. Using generics (as in my answer below) allows one to create the datatable without any elements :)

Comment: Its just an example leppie. Calm down.

Comment: I do appreciate and respect your opinion however. Just wanted you to know that.